# Exchange 2010 API - Connect to company email

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I'm new to using the Exchange 2010 API (C#).  I'm just going through a basic example (link below), but I'm having issues when using the FindItems method.  In particular, I get the error  "ServiceVersionException unhandled".  The first thing that comes to mind is that I've specified the wrong Exchange version, like in this line:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
```

I've tried the different permutations though (and the IT guys tell me its 2010), and still getting the same error.   I was wondering if it could be some weird firewall thing,  or something else.

Any thoughts are much appreciated!

Thanks

Example: http://omegacoder.com/?p=454

EDIT: The inner exception is: "null".

Comment: What if you don't specify a specific version? There are only 3 versions (Exchange2007_SP1, Exchange2010, & Exchange2010_SP1). Maybe SP1 isn't applied.

Comment: I did try without the SP1 like below, but still didn't work...

ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);

Comment: see Edit above for inner exception

Comment: @keynesiancross you should try it like this: [ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd634740%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx). Are you using [Auto Discovery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.autodiscoverurl%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)?

Comment: I am using Auto Discovery.  Tried that line above there, where I don't specify a version, but it still gives the same error.